# changing the language of the iphone app

Tags: iphone

I have a tabbar Controller . which have 5 Tabs in that one is SETTINGS .here the user can change the language of the app, when the user selects the language from settings view, i am using another tabbar controller to reload the views (already 1st tabar is loaded with default language) with the selected language content . is there any other way to change the language of the app instead of using the second tabbar controller

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Jesper—you should follow the phone's language settings instead of making your own setting—but if for some reason you really want to put the language in your own settings, I would do one of the following:

1. Put code in the `viewWillAppear:` method of the View Controllers to check if the language has been changed, and then redo the content in the right language if it has.
2. When the language changes, have your settings view controller tell all the other view controllers to redo their content in the right language. To do that you'll have to set up the other view controllers to be delegates of the settings view controller (or have some other entity, like the App Delegate, intermediate).

Answer (score 0):

According to Apple's guidelines you should not allow the user to change the language of the app in the app itself. Instead you should localize your xib's and text resources, and the language should follow the phone's settings.

Comment: i am giving an option for the user to language from the app settings  . will the apple rejects my app because of this ?

Comment: No, I don't think they'll reject your app. They just advice you to let the app decide the language based on the language of the phone. One less thing the user will have to decide.